# Freebase query - 10000 most popular people

Tags: freebase, mql

I am looking for a way to construct a freebase mql query that will return a list of names of popular ('commonly searched on google') people.

Currently, if I do a simple query like:

```
{
  "type" : "people/person",
  "name" : [],
  "limit" : 5
}
```

I get

```
    "Jack Abramoffa"
    "Bob Ney"
    "David Safavian"
    "Kåre Kristiansen"
    "Adam Murimuth"
```

Is there a way to modify the query in a way that will sort the elements by their google search rank, or any other measure of popularity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it via MQL, but the Freebase Search API returns topics in ranked fashion.  The default scoring algorithm uses how well linked a topic is https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-cookbook#scoring-and-ranking.  Google doesn't provide search query popularity rankings through any of the Freebase APIs.